# Simple library for interactive swipe transitions between view controllers

Tags: ios, swipe, viewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

As the title states, I am looking for a **simple** library that I can use to allow a user to interactively swipe between view controllers (bearing in mind that my application does not have a navigation controller). I know there are several different questions already on SO that answer this but I understand that most of them are quite old, and I was wondering whether iOS 7 had a much simpler solution available. I have spent several days trying to implement different approaches, but in each case, my code gets too messy and becomes riddled with various errors. By the way, all my segues are modal (if that's of any use?).

By **simple** I mean a standalone library that can be called from a gesture recognizer and that is all that's required from that particular view controller

```
-(void)hasswipedright:(UIGestureRecognizer*)Gesture{
//Library Creates transition between this VC and another VC
}
```

I have tried looking into the following attempts:

- https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary
- http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/
- (As well as numerous others that I have abandoned)

I would use a UIScrolView or UIPageContainer but I don't think that would work because I only want to design certain jumps between view controllers to be "swipable" (i.e. B may swipe to A but not the other way, but A can swipe to C and D and viceversa).

Any suggestions? I wish to make the transitions interactive (something like pangesturerecognizer required to go backwards in iOS7's Safari). Any comments are very much appreciated. I don't wish to appear lazy by asking for a library, its just that I don't have the time to reformat absolutely EVERYTHING manually (and furthermore, I'm just a beginner in iOS development!)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers

Check out the function "beingdragged" or something like that. You have two options. You can either setup a pageviewcontroller and then use the delegate methods (they're in that repository as well near the bottom) that dictate the view controllers that show up before and after, so you can check what to do at each swipe, or you can grab the scroll view itself from the pageviewcontroller (see the method "syncscrollview") and then add a custom method (in this case beingdragged) to the gesture recognized. Then you can apply logic to make sure the correct view controllers come up

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I eventually just used a UIPageViewController and boring old "swipe to dismiss" gestures in my second set of Viewcontrollers. I realised that the problem with these libraries is that they all make use of the UIPageViewController which prevents swipe gestures from working (I need a swipe gesture on my first page to jump between different pageviewcontrollers)! However, thanks for the library - it looks awesome and I might make use of it later!

Comment: I feel as though I should just note this down - just to help you! I tried using your library but encountered one rather annoying issue. There was a 20px large buffer between the top of the segmentedcontrol button and the status bar! Whatever I tried, I couldn't remove it! This meant that it didn't fit well with my application unfortunately... Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the comment, if you check the .h, you can customize any of the button setup.  In this case, you want to change the Y_BUFFER.  I'll definitely make note of that though!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you [YZSwipeBetweenViewController](https://github.com/yichizhang/YZSwipeBetweenViewController)

Comment: Is there any library for the same functionality written in swift?

Comment: I dont know right now, but I will comment if I find swift version of this library.

Answer (score 1):

**See at this repo may be helpful.**

It Helps you to create a Controller in which a UiTableViewCell Holding a UiPageViewController with scrollable section header to change the viewController and and these viewControllers are also swiped.

[image]

https://github.com/iossolutions/PBSwipeController

Add these objects and initialize in viewdidload method : -

```
    HeadingArray = @[@"Counting",@"Alphabets",@"Colors",@"Random",@"Names"];
    NSArray *array1 = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];
    NSArray *array2 = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z"];
    NSArray *array3 = @[@"White",@"Orange",@"Blue",@"Green",@"Yellow"];
    NSArray *array4 = @[@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t"];
    NSArray *array5 = @[@"Abhi",@"Kabhi",@"Jabhi",@"Ravi",@"Lavi"];
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:array1,array2,array3,array4,array5, nil];

    [self addInitialObjects];
    [self setupSelector];}
    -(void)addInitialObjects{

    // Add Scroolable object in section header
    self.currentPageIndex = 0;
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,40)];
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:30.0f/255.0f green:144.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    for (int i = 0; i<HeadingArray.count; i++) {
        UIButton  *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(i*100, 0, 100, 40);
        [_scrollView addSubview:button];
        button.tag = i;
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:[HeadingArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in _scrollView.subviews) {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }
    _scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;

    // Page view controller for swipeable view
    UIPageViewController *pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    navigationController = [[PBSwipeController alloc]initWithRootViewController:pageController];
    navigationController.swipeDelegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:navigationController];
    [navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**In Your Cell for row at index pass the data  : -**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        cell1.textLabel.text = @"Cell - Below is section header";
        cell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:127.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    }
    else {
        cell1.textLabel.text = @"";
        cell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        navigationController.pagesNameArray = HeadingArray;
        navigationController.pageDataArray = dataArray;
        [navigationController viewControllerAtIndex:0];
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:navigationController.view];
    }
    return cell1;
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this repo .It is so much simpler and easily understandable for RnD. (Swift 3 code)

https://github.com/lakshikabhardwaj/LBViewControllerCollection

```
let catVC =   CatVC(nibName: "catVC", bundle: nil)    //UIViewController Objects
let cowVC =   CowVC(nibName: "CowVC", bundle: nil)
let elephantVC = ElephantVC(nibName: "ElephantVC", bundle: nil)
let chatVC =   ChatVC(nibName: "ChatVC", bundle: nil)

    let mainViewController = CPPageMenuVC(nibName: "CPPageMenuVC", bundle: nil)

let pageMenuarray :[PageModal] = [PageModal(pageTitle: "Cat", pageVC: catVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "Cow", pageVC: cowVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "Chat", pageVC: chatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "ElephantElephant", pageVC: elephantVC)]
        pageMenuVC.pageArray = pageMenuarray
```